# Weather radar for desktop

Tags: windows, weather

I use a [weather radar app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acmeaom.android.myradar&hl=en) on Android.  it's simple, works well, and does what I want it to do.

I'd like to have the same information available to me while on a Windows desktop or laptop.  Popular weather websites obsficate their radar pages, or I can't seem to get them to work with the suite of security add-ons I have installed in my browser (blocking ads, JavaScript, cookies, etc.).

I'm looking to view the weather radar on a PC.  Features I'd like to see:

- Free or low cost (< $10)
- 1 time fee preferred vs. recurring subscription
- Not a UWP app
- Set location via city or zip code
- Pan and scan
- Looping
- Variable speed playback, including pause
- Clear timestamps as the radar images progress

Comment: Have you tried the NOAA website? Or a local TV station website?

Comment: Any reason that it shall not be a UWP app? I use the builtin Windows 10 weather app, works great, looks great and is my favourite weather app. No need for third-party software here.

Comment: UWP requires UAC, and disabling UAC breaks UWP.  I find myself rolling back "features" more often than not because to me they are bugs, not features.

Answer (score 1):

As far as internet weather sites, I've had the best results from Weather Underground and Accuweather sites. Both offer regional maps with animation and real time updates. I think either will fit your needs.